# Python Plotly: I want to force plotly to connect gaps between lines in a Line Chart

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly, plotly-python

I have this dataframe. It shows a football **player**, his **club** and his **overall** each **year** from 2017 to 2023

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGQXY.png)

The initial idea was to make this line chart, showing the year in X Axis and Overall in Y Axis:

[First Line Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4Wkh.png)

There's the code:

```
line_chart = px.line(data_frame=df_overall_per_year_filtered, x='Year', y='Overall', title='Overall a cada Ano', labels={'Year': 'Ano'}, markers=True)
```

And it's fine, it's working, but after that I thought: Why not show the club too?

Then I modified the code adding `color='Club'` like this:

```
line_chart = px.line(data_frame=df_overall_per_year_filtered, x='Year', y='Overall', title='Overall a cada Ano', labels={'Year': 'Ano'}, markers=True, color='Club')
```

[Second Line Chart with Color: Club](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzSwV.png)

It worked, I mean, almost. It shows Overall by the Years and show the Club by line color. But the lines aren't connected anymore. Is there a way to force `plotly` to fill that gap?

Just like this:

[Desired Line Chart (Made with Paint)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXbzX.png)

**Already Attempted:**

I've already tried this code:

```
line_chart.update_traces(connectgaps=True)
```

but it doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to `pivot` the dataframe and then back-fill (i.e., `bfill`) a single column to "connect" the lines:

```
df2 = df.pivot(index="Year",columns="Club",values="Overall")[df["Club"].unique()]

>>> px.line(df2.bfill(limit=1, axis=1),x=df2.index,y=df2.columns)
```

[image]